# Differential Equation Initial Value Problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

Here is a pretty standard initial value problem that I'm having a little trouble with.
$$(\ln(y))^2\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=x^2y$$
Given $y(1)=e^2$, find the constant $C$.

So I separated and integrated to get $\frac{(\ln(y))^3}{3}=\frac{x^3}{3}+C$. Multiplying $3$ to both sides yields $(ln(y))^3=x^3+C$. Here's where I struggled a little.  So I take the cube root of both sides to get $\ln y=\sqrt[3]{x^3+C}$ then raised $e$ to both sides to get $y=e^\sqrt[3]{x^3+C}$...? Basically, the $C$ and the $e$ are giving me trouble.  I appreciate any pointers.

Comment: I'm sorta new to differential equations. Could you explain how you got $\ln^3y=x^3$? I got the following equation instead:
$$y(\ln^2y-2\ln y+2)=\frac{x^3}{3}$$

Comment: @Hrhm, you solved $\int(ln(y))^2\,\mathrm{d}y$ but after separation of variables the correct integration is $\int\frac{(ln(y))^2}{y}\,\mathrm{d}y$

Comment: @user338955 thanks, I appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

It may be easier to solve for $C$ at the step

$$(\ln y)^3=x^3+C$$

$$2^3=1^3+C$$.

Everything else looks good.

Comment: thank you, turns out that was a much better idea

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the $C$ in your first equation is not the $C$ in your second equation.  (If the first $C$ was called $C_1$, the second $C$ would be equal to $3C_1$.)

You have $y(1)=e^2$.  Plugging $x=1$ and $y=e^2$ into your last equation yields $e^2=e^\sqrt[3]{1^2+C}$, thus, $2=\sqrt[3]{1+C}$.  Can you do the rest?

Comment: Yep i got it, thank you

Answer (score 0):

$$y'(x)\ln^2(y(x))=y(x)x^2\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{y'(x)\ln^2(y(x))}{y(x)}=x^2\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\int\frac{y'(x)\ln^2(y(x))}{y(x)}\space\text{d}x=\int x^2\space\text{d}x\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

For the LHS, subtitute $u=\ln(y(x))$ and $\text{d}u=\frac{y'(x)}{y(x)}\space\text{d}x$.

---

$$\frac{\ln^3(y(x))}{3}=\frac{x^3}{3}+\text{C}$$

Now, use $y(1)=e^2$:

$$\frac{\ln^3(e^2)}{3}=\frac{1^3}{3}+\text{C}\Longleftrightarrow\text{C}=\frac{7}{3}$$

So, we get:

$$\ln^3(y(x))=7+x^3$$

Now, because of the initial condition, you can only use the real solution:

$$y(x)=\exp\left[\sqrt[3]{7+x^3}\right]$$